# Maximize and minimize in Android

Tags: android

I get want to know whether we can maximize and minimize a whole application.

It should work like ALT+TAB in windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible. You should read [Component Lifecycles](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#lcycles)

Kinda Alt + TAB on some Android devices works like holding longer the Home button, but is nothing like that in functionality.